# Return String in function and use println! macro

Tags: rust

I think why following code does not work at all:

```
fn say_hello(string: &str) -> String {
    println!("Hello to{}", string)
}
```

but very similar code works fine:

```
fn say_hello(string: &str) -> String {
    format!("Hello to{}", string)
}
```

Why I am not able to use `println!` macro having `-> String` in above code?

Comment: Because `println!` doesn't return a String. It prints one to stdout, but doesn't return it.

Comment: cause you didn't give any reason why you think the first snipped should work or what you expect it to do. A simple quick read of the documentation will give you the answer.

Comment: OK, I will read more docs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function specifically says that you will return a `String`:

```rust
fn say_hello(string: &str) -> String
```

`println!` returns `()`. Since those types do not match, it will not compile.

To solve this, and as an example, you could return the `str` as a new `String`:

```rust
fn say_hello(string: &str) -> String {
    println!("Hello to{}", string); // Not returning the expression
    string.to_string()
}
```

Comment: Except it will return the original string, not one decorated with "hello". But yes, it least this should compile.

Comment: Except that it won't compile because `str` is a type, you meant `string.to_string()`